# Why does my XGBoost model that loaded by Scala API and used by broadcast in Spark run so slowly?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, broadcast, xgboost

I have a XGBoost model trained by python API, and now I just want to use it in spark to predict massive data that about 300 million. I just use the loadModel API of the Scala's XGBoost to load the model in Spark driver and then I broadcast the model to all executors to execute the prediction operation. I use 500 executors,and 4G memory & 1 core on each executor, but it is too slowly that can't be accepted. It maybe runs 15 hours to be finished.

But when I test in the single jvm, it is very fast that can predict more than 200 records per second at least, so the Spark job should be finished just less an hour when using 500 cores, but why it so slowly?

the code as below:

```
sc.addFile("hdfs://xxxxxxx/model/mash/data/my_train.model")
val fpd30Model =  XGBoost.loadModel(SparkFiles.get("my_train.model"))
val model30Bdc =  sc.broadcast(fpd30Model)

val resultRdd = sc.textFile("hdfs://xxxxxxx/model/mash/data/30_features/").repartition(5000)
  .map(row=>{
    val data = row.split("\t")
    val miId = data(0)
    val features = data(1).split(",").map(row=>row.toFloat)
    val score = model30Bdc.value.predict(new DMatrix(features, 1, 225, Float.NaN))(0)(0)
    Array(miId, score).mkString("\t")
  }).repartition(100)

val output = "hdfs://xxxxxxx/model/mash/score/30_score/"
HdfsIo.removePath(sc, output)

resultRdd.saveAsTextFile(output)
```

Comment: How many executors are you using in your application? You seem to say you've given 500 cores per executor which doesn't seem right. Can you please clarify that too?

Comment: OK, I mean use 500 executors in my Spark job and 1 core per executor to execute the code above, and it is slowly. But when I test in a scala class(not a spark job, just an usual scala object) with main function which I construct a feature list to run the scala xgboost predict function, it is fast that can predict more than 200 records per second at least.

Comment: And how big is your model file? A few small MBs or a relatively huge GBs?

Comment: The model file is very small which is just 140KB.

Comment: I was thinking probably it was a large model which takes time to get redistributed. It's hard to debug what's taking time. I would run the job. SSH into one of the nodes run `jps` against the process to figure out what is it doing.